# Naming Conflict in Method Scoping

Tags: c#, language-design

> Within a method, there can only be one object of any given name. We
>   got away with reusing the same variable names using the block level
>   scoping of our loop control variables in an earlier example, however,
>   an object of the same name outside of the block scope will show why
>   that does not work. See this example showing this naming conflict:

```
public static void DoWork()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
    int i = 777; // Compiler error here
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

Above are from https://www.microsoft.com/net/tutorials/csharp/getting-started/scope-accessibility, I want to ask why will this happen? Why does c# be designed like this, since C++ and Java has nothing like this.(I have tested, in Java and C++ there are not limits)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[According to Eric Lippert](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/11/02/simple-names-are-not-so-simple/), this design choice was done in order to

> prevent the class of bugs in which the reader/maintainer of the code
>   is tricked into believing they are referring to one entity with a
>   simple name, but are in fact accidentally referring to another entity
>   entirely.

This sort of thing can particularly bite you when you refactor, and seemingly innocent changes can alter completely the meaning of the code.

Comment: Excellent! Would you please tell me how you find this article?

Comment: I remembered reading it somewhere, and googled a few times to find it. :)

Answer (score 0):

The statement you mentioned in the beginning of your question is not 100% correct.

If you will use the below code, compiler will not generate errors

```
public static void DoWork()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
        { 
          // adding this block will remove the compiler error, 
          // and yes you can use the same variable name in the same 
          // method but you need to help the compiler that each 
          // variable usuage is under its own block.
            int i = 777; // Not compiler error anymore
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
    }
```

The compiler error mentioned above in your question is most probably to prevent the misuse of the variable

Hope this will help you